# Probability problem dependent events

Tags: probability

Company X has 800 employees and Company Y has 600 employees. Among these employees, there are 50 married couples, each consisting of an employee from Company X and an employee from Company Y. If 1 employee is to be selected at random from each company, what is the probability that the 2 employees selected will be a married couple?

Original Ans : 1/9600

My approach : choose a married person from X , get the corresponding spouse + choose a married person from Y, get the corresponding spouse -- 50/800 * 1/600 + 50/600 * 1/800. This gives 1/4800.

Doubt 1 - Why is my approach wrong.

Doubt 2 - Also how's the above question different from this question - Basket contains 2 red, 3 green and 4 black balls. Whats the probability of drawing 1 green and 1 red without replacement?

Ans - 2/9*3/8 + 3/9*2/8 = 1/6

Comment: You've double counted your married couples in your probability calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My approach : choose a married person from X , get the corresponding spouse + choose a married person from Y, get the corresponding spouse -- 50/800 * 1/600 + 50/600 * 1/800. This gives 1/4800.
>
> Doubt 1 - Why is my approach wrong.

You are double counting. You only have to count once. The correct approach is using conditional probability: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cap B) &= \mathsf P(A)\;\mathsf P(B\mid A)
\\ & = \frac{50}{800}\frac{1}{600}
\end{align}$$

Another way to look at it: There are $800\times 600$ distinct possible ways to pair one person from company $X$ with one person from company $Y$, but only $50$ of these will bring together a married couple.

> Doubt 2 - Also how's the above question different from this question - Basket contains 2 red, 3 green and 4 black balls. Whats the probability of drawing 1 green and 1 red without replacement?
>
> Ans - 2/9*3/8 + 3/9*2/8 = 1/6

In the first case you were drawing from two different sources, which makes the order irrelevant (when it is time to draw from company $X$ you can only get an employee from company $X$, and then from company $Y$ ...).

In this case you are drawing from the *same pool* (one basket) and so the order of the draw matters.  On the first draw you can get any ball from the basket, and on the second draw you can get any remaining ball from that basket.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P((A_1\cap B_2) \cup (B_1\cap A_2)) & = \mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(B_2\mid A_1)+\mathsf P(B_1)\mathsf P (A_2\mid B_1)
\end{align}$$

Another way to look at it: There are 2 ways to choose a red ball, and 3 ways to choose a green, out of all the ways to choose any 2 balls from all 9.

$$\begin{align}
\\ & = \frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{9}{2}}
\\ & = \frac{2\cdot 3}{(9\cdot 8)/2}
\\ & = \frac 1 6
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, the way to answer this problem is the following: 
you choose randomly an employee from company X who is married ,  and this have propability $ \frac{25}{800}$, now you have to choose his corresponding couple from company Y, and so you are choosing one specific employee and this has a probability $\frac{1}{600}$. Now taking the reverse order, so first choose an employee from company Y who is married:  $ \frac{25}{600}$, and choose his corresponding coulpe from Company X, with probibility $\frac{1}{800}$. Thus totaly your probability is:
 $$P=\frac{25}{800} \times \frac{1}{600} + \frac{25}{600} \times   \frac{1}{800} = \frac{1}{9600} $$
Doubt $1$. : What you did in your answer is that you suppose each company has $50$ married employees, where as the "50 married couples, each consisting of an employee from Company X and an employee from Company Y", so there are $25$ married employee in company X and $25$ married employee. ( I think here there is a linguistic uncertainty by saying $50$ couples! meaning each wife and husband count one or two )

Doubt $2$. : The two cases mentioned above differ by: first in the companies case there are two different companies, as if  you are selecting from two distict baskets, even if you dont have replacement, the number of the over all balls in  the basket will change. On the other hand, the second idea is that you are free in slecting the red and the green balls. For example, if you associate for the red balls numbering $1,2$, and for the green balls $1,2,3$, and you ask to select one red and one green with same number labling, in this way you will be in a similar case to the selected married coulpes from the  two companies.

Comment: No, it is 50 pairs; dividing that by 2 *misleadingly* gives the right answer because the *method is double counting.*  We only have to do it one way:  Pick a member of one company that belongs to one of the 50 pairs, and pick a member of the other company that belongs to the same pair.